# What are the differences in some of the OpenCV commands?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm really sorry if my question might be too noob or something else. But, I find my self a little bit confusing between some commands found in OpenCV.
After browsing [the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/) , I found that there are commands like cvMemStorage and cv::MemStorage, cvMat and cv::Mat, cvSeq and cv::Seq, cvNormalBayesClassifier and cv::NormalBayesClassifier.

So, what are the differences between those commands?

Are they just a different style of commands between the C and C++ style?

So why don't they (OpenCV team) just use one style in most of the c and c++ world?

Any help and comments would be really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The most important reason is backward compatibility, clients will hate you if you break their codes. Whatever, stick with the c++ style api if your target platform support decent c++ compiler, this will save you from a lot of troubles.

Comment: From the tutorial of openCV "The main downside of the C++ interface is that many embedded development systems at the moment support only C. Therefore, unless you are targeting embedded platforms, there’s no point to using the old methods (unless you’re a masochist programmer and you’re asking for trouble)."  docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer

Answer (score 2):

The convention seems to be that `cvSomething` is a C type or function, and `cv::Something` is the corresponding C++ version. In C++, `cv` is a `namespace`.

OpenCV maintains both C and a C++ interfaces, which is the reason you get both variants (there are also python bindings, which can make the all-in-one documentation confusing).

Comment: So, it is just a different style for C and C++ version? Am I right?
Do you know the equivalent C++ version for cvCreateMemStorage and cvCreateSeq?

Comment: @hxr99 it is not just a different style. The `cv::` versions are actual C++ types anf functions. Quite often they are wrappers that use the C API under the hood. I am not sure about those two functions you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

The core library of OpenCV version 2.x is written in C++. The coding convention is to have everything in the namespace `cv`. (See [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/CodingStyleGuide) or [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#cv-namespace)).

The old API (version 1.x) was a C API. The convention was to add the prefix `cv`.

The old 1.x API is still exposed to client code. Usually, you will not need it. (As stated in the OpenCV documentation for [Dynamic structure](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html?highlight=cvcreatememstorage#) (since you referenced the cvCreateMemStorage), "if you use the new C++, Python, Java etc interface, you will unlikely need this functionality. Use std::vector or other high-level data structures.")